# Translations Editor in Android Studio Other Than strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using `arrays.xml` to store arrays rather than storing in `strings.xml` for the sake of tidiness of my code. I need to translate my elements in the array into different languages.

Is there a way to use translations editor for that purpose as in the `strings.xml` file, as the notification bar automatically appears whenever I open `strings.xml` but not in the `arrays.xml`?

Comment: Sadly, there are no other ways currently. Android Studio only shows translation editor for `strings.xml`

Comment: And even there it's missing things like `plurals`